# How to filter TCP packets based on flags using Packet Filter

Tags: networking, firewall, filtering, pf, flags

Well, I didn't know exactly how to ask this question, but I know that you can use the keyword flags to especify which flags you want to filter.

According to the documentation of the Packet filter:

> To have PF inspect the TCP flags during evaluation of a rule, the
>   flags keyword is used with the following syntax:
>
> flags check/mask flags any
>
> The mask part tells PF to only inspect the specified flags and the
>   check part specifies which flag(s) must be "on" in the header for a
>   match to occur. Using the any keyword allows any combination of flags
>   to be set in the header.
>
> pass in on fxp0 proto tcp from any to any port ssh flags S/SA pass in
>   on fxp0 proto tcp from any to any port ssh
>
> As flags S/SA is set by default, the above rules are equivalent, Each
>   of these rules passes TCP traffic with the SYN flag set while only
>   looking at the SYN and ACK flags. A packet with the SYN and ECE flags
>   would match the above rules, while a packet with SYN and ACK or just
>   ACK would not.

So, I understood the example and why the packet with the flags S and E can pass (because the E flag is not considered due to the mask SA) and why the packet with only the Ack flag can't pass the firewall.

What I didn't understand is why the packet with the flags S and A can't pass the rule S/SA, if the flag S is "on" in the packet header. Maybe the documentation is ambiguous? Sorry if this is a stupid question or an english misunderstood.

I imagine that it can only pass if it MUST HAS ONLY the flag S. In set arithmetic would be something like this:

flag(s) must be 'on' in the header -> flag(s) pertains to the masked subset [pf doc]
only the flag(s) must be 'on' in the header -> flag(s) is egual to the masked subset [what I understood from the example given]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This means that you're looking at two flags `S` & `A` but you match if and only if `S` is "on" AND `A` is "off".

```
flags S/SA

 ---------------
| S | A | Match |
 ---|---|-------
| 0 | 0 | No    |
| 0 | 1 | No    |
| 1 | 0 | Yes   |
| 1 | 1 | No    |
 ---------------
```

If you want to match when both `SA` flags are "on", you'll use `flags SA/SA`.

```
flags SA/SA

 ---------------
| S | A | Match |
 ---|---|-------
| 0 | 0 | No    |
| 0 | 1 | No    |
| 1 | 0 | No    |
| 1 | 1 | Yes   |
 ---------------
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking after looking the example @Spack . Don't you agree the documentation is ambiguous? It says that the flag(s) in the check part must be 'on' in the header. So the case you pointed when you have S and A, would also match. It doesn't say that only the flag(s) in the check part must match

Comment: I agree with you on that point. As I also use `iptables` on Linux I deducted that the behavior should be similar.